# cassandra how to select token for compound primary key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, scylla

I want to get the token for a row of my table whose primary key looks like this:

`PRIMARY KEY ((C1, C2), C3)`

I tried selecting with the following

`SELECT token((C1, C2), C3) from myTable`

but get an error 
`SyntaxException: line 1:12 no viable alternative at input '('`

what is the proper syntax for this type of query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Token could be called only on the partition key part of the primary key. In your case it will be

```
select token(C1, C2) from myTable;
```

Comment: then how can I do a fuil table scan with pages?

Comment: Here is example: https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TokenRangesScan.java

Comment: I think you have a problem if the query timeouts when the token range is too large and also the token is only taken on "id". If your clustering key range is larger then the token page size, you may be re-reading the same ranges no?

Comment: No... That's algorithm that is used by spark cassandra connector, and other products. also - clustering key don't have ranges - they are generated only for partition keys

Comment: so i don't understand how to pages. What if I only want to pull 1k lines each iteration and partition key has 5k lines (5k clustering keys)

Comment: set fetch size to 1k: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/paging/